# HTML table footer is coming before the header

Tags: html, footer

I am just trying to make a simple table in HTML, I understand that the tfoot element should be rendered before the body, so you place it between the body and the thead element.
I've tried placing it before and after the body, but I still get the table below.

This is the footer of the table

A table

List Type   Tags

Ordered List    <ol>, <li>

Unordered List  <ul>, <li>

Term and Definition list    <dl>, <dt>, <dd>

```
<head></head>
<body>
<table>
<caption>A table</caption>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>List Type</th>
<th>Tags</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody><tr><td>Ordered List</td><td>&lt;ol&gt;, &lt;li&gt;</td></tr><tr><td>Unordered List</td><td>&lt;ul&gt;, &lt;li&gt;</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Term and Definition list</td><td>&lt;dl&gt;, &lt;dt&gt;, &lt;dd&gt;</td>    </tr>
 <tfoot>
 This is the footer of the table
 </tfoot>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

What gives?

Comment: you're not supposed to put content right after `<tfoot>` you need to add `<tr>` and `<td>`

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_tbody

Comment: @FabioG put that in an answer please

Comment: *Aside*: Where does your `tbody` end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're not supposed to put content right after `<tfoot>` you need to add `<tr>` and `<td>`

Answer (score 1):

Use `<tr>` and `<td>` tags in  Footer

```
  <tfoot>
      <tr><td>This is the footer of the table</td></tr>
 </tfoot>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/q8x3ykkj/)